# Word VBA: How can I jump to the next instance of multiple search terms each time the user presses their shorcut?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Desired outcome is when the user presses their shortcut, the cursor jumps to the next instance of multiple search terms. For now let's say "[Ff]izz" and "[Bb]uzz". I don't want to make any changes, just jump forward through the doc to the next instance.

Current code is as follows, but what it's doing is jumping to the next instance of "fizz" if Wrap is set to wdFindStop, or "buzz" if Wrap is set to wdFindContinue or wdFindAsk. If a line was just "Fizz buzz buzz fizz", I'd like it to be able to select each individual word in order from left to right.

```
Sub FizzBuzzFinder()


Dim StrFind As String
Dim i As Long

StrFind = "[Ff]izz,[Bb]uzz"

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Wrap = wdFindAsk
  .Forward = True
  For i = 0 To UBound(Split(StrFind, ","))
    .Text = Split(StrFind, ",")(i)
    .Execute
  Next i
End With


End Sub
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue was your For Loop. It searches for Fizz, selects it, then searches for Buzz, advancing though the text. Since this happens together, the user only sees it select Buzz.

To correct this, I removed the For loop and changed the search string from two items to one item that matches either Fizz or Buzz.

```vb
Sub FizzBuzzFinder()

Dim StrFind As String
Dim i As Long

StrFind = "[FfBb][ui]zz"

Selection.Find.ClearFormatting

With Selection.Find
  .MatchWildcards = True
  .Wrap = wdFindAsk
  .Forward = True
  .Text = StrFind
  .Execute
End With

End Sub
```

Unfortunately, this also matches Fuzz and Bizz.

Comment: Cheers for the reply. I'm not sure how well this'll work in practice as the search terms are going to be a bit more complex than Fizz and Buzz - I'm trying to use it to find "[Ff]rom/[Bb]etween followed by any number, sometimes including decimals, units of currency, percentage signs etc, followed by either a hyphen or an en dash", so I need to have a list of unique wildcard searches it can look for simultaneously.